# Line integral for three line segments

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find [image]
 where C consists of the three line segments from  (2,0,0) to (2,1,0) to (0,1,0) to (0,1,5).

I tried to find it like the other line integral but it seems that there is something wrong!

Answer (score 2):

First, split up $C$ into segments $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$. Now you should parametrise each segment separately and calculate the line integral of $\mathbf F = (x^2 + 2y, 2y^3, 0)$ along each. Then using linearity, you can add up the line integrals to get the total line integral along $C$.

I'll demonstrate how to calculate the first integral.

Parametrise $C_1$ by $\mathbf r_1(t) = (2, t, 0)$, with $t$ ranging from $ 0$ to $1$. Then $\mathbf r'_1(t) = (0, 1, 0)$. Now we calculate the integral:

$$\int_{C_1} \mathbf F \cdot d\mathbf r = \int_0^1 (4+2t, 2t^3, 0) \cdot (0,1,0) dt = \int_0^1 2t^3 dt = \frac{1}{2}$$

The other integrals are similar. Just remember to parametrise correctly, and take the right range for your parametrisation!